# Is it possible to upgrade and/or move Amazon RDS reserved instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I know you can upgrade on-demand RDS instances. But is it possible to upgrade a reserved RDS instance?

Is it also possible to move a reserved RDS instance from one region to another?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Amazon seem to handle this stuff on a case-by-case basis. They have always been reasonable with us. We have upgraded and moved regions in the past without any problems but it will require a phonecall.

Comment: Thanks. It seems like a strange way to handle this, but at least they have a mechanism for dealing with such issues.

Comment: You *entered a contract* where Amazon agreed to provide you with a specific amount of capacity in a specific location, with a discount in consideration for your commitment to continue to pay for those specific resources.  "Region, DB Engine, DB Instance Class, Deployment Type and term length must be chosen at purchase, and cannot be changed later." -- http://aws.amazon.com/rds/reserved-instances/ To whatever extent they are more flexible about this than the documentation suggests, it would be out of courtesy, not out of obligation.